# Result set not returning what is expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query and am getting results I don't expect. Here is the query:

```
USE SCRUMAPI2

DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@startDateParam DATETIME
    ,@endDateParam DATETIME
    ,@orgTeamPK VARCHAR(100)
    ,@teamId VARCHAR(100)
    ,@productId VARCHAR(100)

SET @userParam = '%'
SET @startDateParam = '2013-10-14 00:00:00'
SET @endDateParam = '2013-10-20 23:59:59'
SET @orgTeamPK = '%'
SET @teamId = '%'
SET @productId = '%'

    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN USR.[Deleted] IS NULL
                    THEN 'Active'
                ELSE 'Inactive'
                END
            ) AS [Status]
        ,USR.OrganizationalTeamId AS OrganizationalTeam
        ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN TSK.NAME IS NULL
                    THEN NULL
                WHEN SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description] IS NULL
                    THEN 'KanBan'
                ELSE SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description]
                END
            ) AS Sprint
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], SCY.Catagory) AS Story
        ,COALESCE(TSK.[Name], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS Task
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
    LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory 
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application 
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN1 ON (
            PDT.PK_Product = UAN1.ProductId
            AND UAN1.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    LEFT JOIN UserAuthorization UAN2 ON (
            OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam = UAN2.OrganizationalTeamId
            AND UAN2.Deleted IS NULL
            )
    WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND COALESCE(USR.OrganizationalTeamId, '') LIKE @orgTeamPK
        AND (
            COALESCE(UAN1.ProductId, '') LIKE @productId
            OR COALESCE(UAN2.OrganizationalTeamId, '') LIKE @teamId
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,TSK.[Name]
        ,OLT.[Name]
        ,USR.[Deleted]
        ,APP.AppName
        ,SCY.Catagory
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,USR.OrganizationalTeamId
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
```

Here is part of the result set:

[image]

For the results of the first user two of the OrganizationTeams column cells return NULL. I don't understand why this is, this user is assigned the org team of 3:

[image]

Why isn't it returning 3 for all cells of this user and how can I ensure it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OrganizationalTeam Column is joined in via DailyTaskHours > Task > ProductTeamUser > User. Each join can result in a NULL value so check each of these joins. Try running that Query with `SELECT *` and using a `WHERE` to return only one of those two rows.